# Fitch Proof help please

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, fitch, predicate-logic

[image]

I think I got it, could you take a look, please.

Comment: *What* have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start you on your journey.  You want to derive a negation.  Use a proof by negation introduction.  Assume `Tmm`, introduce an existential, and then use the premises to derive the contrary too.

```
|  (∃x)(Rx)                           (Premise)
|  (∃x)(~Sx)                          (Premise)
|_ (∀x)(∀y)(~(Rx → Sy) → ~(∃z)(Tmz))  (Premise)
|  |_ Tmm                              (Assumption)
|  |  (∃z)(Tmz)                        (Existential Introduction)
|  |  :
|  |  :
|  |  ~(∃z)(Tmz)                       (Negation Introduction)
|  |  #                                (Negation Elimination)
|  ~Tmm                                (Negation Introduction)
```

---

> I have followed your steps and also uploaded where I get stuck. Could you take a look and give me some suggestions, please. Thank you – Stanley
>
> ```
> 1   |   (Ex)Rx                             Premise
> 2   |   (Ex)~Sx                            Premise
> 3   |_  (Ax)(Ay)(~(Rx > Sy) > ~(Ez)Tmz)    Premise
> 4   | |_  Ra                               Assumption
> 5   | | |_  ~Sb                            Assumption
> 6   | | |   (Ra & ~Sb)                     4,5  &I
>     : : :
> ```

That is not according to my advice.  My suggested goal is to derive `~(Ez)Tmz` so that you can derive a contradiction under the assumption of `Tmm`.  You could do that if you could derive `~(Ra > Sb)`; since universal eliminations of the third premise gives `~(Ra > Sb) > ~(Ez)Tmz` .  So... try that.

```
 1   |   (Ex)Rx                             Premise
 2   |   (Ex)~Sx                            Premise
 3   |_  (Ax)(Ay)(~(Rx > Sy) > ~(Ez)Tmz)    Premise
 4   |  |_ Tmm                              Assumption
 5   |  |  (Ez)Tmz                          E Introduction 4
 6   |  |  |_ Ra                            Assumption
 7   |  |  |  |_ ~Sb                        Assumption
 8   |  |  |  |  |_ Ra > Sy                 Assumption
     :  :  :  :  :  :
     :  :  :  :  :
 m   |  |  |  |  ~(Ez)Tmz                   :
 n   |  |  |  ~(Ez)Tmz                      E Elimination 2,7-m
 o   |  |  ~(Ez)Tmz                         E Elimination 1,6-n
 p   |  |  #                                ~ Elimination 5,o
 q   |  ~Tmm                                ~ Introduction 4-p
```

Comment: Hi Graham Kemp, I have followed your steps and also uploaded where I get stuck. Could you take a look and give me some suggestions, please. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I tried it and I think I got it. Could you take a look and check it?

Comment: Also, I have another question posted if you can take a look.https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81003/question-about-proving-a-set-that-is-quantificationally-inconsistent-in-pd-fin

Comment: ...  Just use Conditional Elimination.  `Ra, (Ra -> Sb) |- Sb`, so therefore `Ra, ~Sb |- ~(Ra -> Sb)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, at a broad level, ∀x ∀y [~(~Rx ∨ Sy) → ~(∃z Tmz)] is equivalent to ∀x ∀y [(Rx ∧ ~Sy) → ~(∃z Tmz)].  Your other two premises tell you that there is an x and a y such that (Rx ∧ ~Sy).  This implies the conclusion, ~(∃z Tmz).  This is equivalent to ∀z ~Tmz, and then you can instantiate z with m, yielding ~Tmm.

Your proof should generally follow that logic.  You just need to translate each step into a Fitch proof in your system.

Comment: I only know (∃x)Rx and  (∃x)~Sx can be combined to  ((∃x)Rx &  (∃x)~Sx), but this can not imply ~(∃z Tmz) because they are not ∀x ∀y ~(Rx → Sy). Could you tell me what move should I take to make it happen? Thank you

Comment: @Stanley you first need to use existential elimination on the first two premises to obtain Rx ∧ ~Sy (where x and y have not yet been used as free variables).  Then use universal elimination to obtain (Rx ∧ ~Sy) → ~(∃z Tmz).

Comment: Ok, I got the result of (∃x)(∃y)(Rx & ~Sy), but can I use universal elimination directly to (∀x)(∀y)~(Rx → Sy) → ~(∃z)Tmz? since it is a conditional sentence.

Comment: @Stanley you need to use existential elimination, to go from (∃x)(∃y)(Rx & ~Sy) to just Rx & ~Sy  (where x and y have not been used as free variables before in your proof).

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how (∃x)(∃y)(Rx & ~Sy) can go to Ra & ~Sb by existential elimination. could you tell me more about it, please?

Comment: @Stanley http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/notes/chapter_08.html scroll down to where it says "existential elimination."  The rule is that from ∃x p(x), you can derive the plain expression p(x), *provided* you have not previously used x as a free variable.  (If you have already used x as a free variable you would instead instantiate as p(y) or p(w) or something you haven't used.)

Comment: Thanks for your patient, I could not start any things without your comment. I read the article and read the moment below and finally get it now. Thanks again.